# Insert sql query result to a new query

Tags: php, sql

So the task is:

- 1. Do a query like Select * from table.
- 2. Take some cell value
- 3. Insert this value to a new query.

What do I have so far:
    $Conn = odbc_connect("...");
    $Result = odbc_exec("Select ...");
    while($r = odbc_fetch_array($Result))
    // showing result in a table

Here it looks like I should use the `r` array and insert data like

```
$var = r['some_field'];
$query = 'Select * from table where some_field = {$var}";
```

But how can I fill this array with values and how to make it available out of while loop?
Here I'm using odbc, but it doesn't matter, I need the algorithm. Thanks.

The whole code looks like:

```
<?php
$data = array();
$state = 'false';
if($_REQUEST['user_action']=='')
{
    $Conn = odbc_connect("...");
    $data = array();     

    if($_REQUEST['name']!='')
    {                                                 
        $Result = odbc_exec($Conn, "select ...");
        //Showing result table
        while($r = odbc_fetch_array(Result))
        {                 
            array_push($data, $r['cardgroup']); 
            $state = 'true';     
        }
            //   print_r($data);  WORKS;             
    }    
}  

if ($_REQUEST['user_action'] == 'action1')
           {     
                //I need to use $data HERE. Doesn't work
                // $state = 'false' here...
           }
?>
```

Comment: why dont you fill some array inside loop,that you can use that new array outside of loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define array outside while loop

```
$data = array();//defining
while($r = odbc_fetch_array($Result))
```

use [**array_push()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) inside while loop

```
array_push($data, $r['some_field']);
```

then try to print array of complete data outside loop

```
print_r($data);
```

### Updates

---

Place `$data = array();` at the top of first `IF` statement. Try this code:

```
$data = array();//at top   
if($_REQUEST['user_action']=='')
{
    $Conn = odbc_connect("...");  

    if($_REQUEST['name']!='')
    {                                                 
        $Result = odbc_exec($Conn, "select ...");
        //Showing result table
        while($r = odbc_fetch_array(Result))
        {                 
            array_push($data, $r['cardgroup']); 
        }
            //   print_r($data);  WORKS;             
    }    
}  

if ($_REQUEST['user_action'] == 'action1')
{     
      //print_r($data) works here also
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works fine. But I use it all inside the if statement... so the $data becomes empty out of if statement. The new trouble...

Comment: @Daria need to see complete code updated your question. and if it helps please accept answer

Comment: I'll put it into question.

Comment: damn! It works OUT of if statement, but inside of if ($_REQUEST['user_action'] == 'action1') it is EMPTY! What's wrong?? God..

Comment: @Daria it should work as i can see. May be problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I guess no. If I assign some $var='false' before if($_REQUEST['user_action']=='') and set it to 'true' inside the if($_REQUEST['user_action']==''), so it becomes false in if ($_REQUEST['user_action'] == 'action1')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61271/discussion-between-manwal-and-daria).

Answer (score 2):

try something like this to store data in array

```
$allrows = array();

while($r = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){
    $allrows[] = $r;
}
```

use foreach loop to print or use as per your choice

```
foreach($allrows as $singlerow) {
   //use it as you want, for insert/update or print all key value like this
   foreach($singlerow as $key => $value) {
       //echo $key . '=='. $value;            
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as i understand your query hope this is your answer

```
$arr ='';

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($Result)) { 

    $arr .= '\''.$row['some_field'].'\','; 
} 

$arr = trim($arr, ",");

$query = "SELECT * from table where some_field IN ($arr)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your all task can be completed in single query

```
INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, ..., coln)
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM table1
```